# Periodically update database

Tags: sql, mongodb, database

Given a database (currently **MongoDB**) is there a proper and efficient way to periodically update **all** the values of the database?.

Let's say I want certain values to decrease by 1 every second or so, and to get notified when those values reach 0 in my app. I would like to avoid (if possible) updating them manually from my app iterating over all the elements as it could get pretty inefficient to query and update all the database every second.

I'm interested in answers for other databases apart from mongo

Thanks

Comment: That is the wrong approach.  Put in a time stamp, and when you *query* the database, do the calculation.

Comment: I need to be notified when the values reaches 0, using timestamps would require me to perform the query I want to avoid anyway

Comment: First of all, you should select the proper tags for your question (SQL and MONGODB are very different in all aspects). Second, your question implies that the DB takes proactive actions... In fact, the approach should be that the process that ticks every pre-defined period of time, would select the difference from the values in the table and a single counter. When the difference becomes zero or less, trigger the notification (by the way, you can make the select such that it will only pick those cases that require notification). This is the general idea. Implementation: DB dependent.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB don't have notification if something happen on the server (example, a Trigger). Even more you can't create this type of logic (decrease the time until is 0 second) also because i don't see benefit to have into the Database the "seconds left".

If you are making a kind of "eBay" where an Item has a "time to live" before became invalidate then you can resolve it with MongoDB with **findOneAndUpdate** or **updateMany**.